# Is there a word for this geological formation?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a very tall, narrow rock formation whose base is on the sea floor and the tip is above sea level?

There is this [similar formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoodoo_(geology)) above sea level.

Comment: You may also find http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ helpful for any future questions about Earth Science.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called **stacks** or **seastacks**. They are typically a coastal formation, as they form from headland erosion.

Description from the [U.S Geological Survey](http://geomaps.wr.usgs.gov/parks/sea/gseastack.html):

> Sea stacks are blocks of erosion-resistant rock isolated from the land by sea. Sea stacks begin as part of a headland or sea cliff. Relentless pounding by waves erodes the softer, weaker parts of a rock first, leaving harder, more resistant rock behind.

You may also find more information at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28geology%29).

Comment: There are also undersea [hydrothermal vents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_vent), giving rise to *[black] **smokers***. They may be particularly important, since increasing numbers of scientists now suspect that's where life on earth first got started (long before the surface was cool, calm, and comet-free enough for early biochemistry to make any headway).